# How to efficiently parse command-line arguments in C

Tags: c, arguments, command-line-arguments, argv, argc

I have a program that needs to parse command line arguments and pass them to various functions to perform different tasks.

Some of the possible options and possible arguments are:

- `-a <source> <destination>`
- `-b <filename>`
- `-p --num <number>`
- `-r --identical <source> <destination>`
- `-g --alphabetical <destination>`

As you can see the various options are quite diverse and are not limited to something simple such as `-f <x>` but instead it has various parameters and arguments also (for example `-r`).

I have looked into `getopt_long`/`getopt` but these do not completely satisfy the full range of my programs options. For example i cannot do `-r --identical <source> <destination>`.

So i have resorted to parsing myself:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

     if (argc == 1)
     {
         fprintf(stderr,"no args");
         return -1;
     }

     if (argc == 4)
     {
        if (strncmp("-a", argv[1], 3) == 0)
        {
            a_function(argv[2], argv[3]);
        }
     }
     else if (argc == 3)
     {
          if (strncmp("-b", argv[1], 3) == 0)
          {
              another_func(argv[2]);
          }
     }


    return 0;
}
```

The program above relies on the number of arguments provided, my question is: is there a more effective/cleaner way to parse arguments (specifically the ones i defined above) since if i carry on, then my program will have a huge list of `if` statements, which doesnt look very clean at all. if there is a better and more effective way i would appreciate some help in implementing it.

Answer (score 1):

It is quite a complex task and I would suggest using a ready-made library.

1. POSIX `getopt`
   https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html
   or
2. GNU `argp`
   https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Argp.html

Answer (score 0):

This library will do the task clean and well: https://github.com/XUJINKAI/cmdparser/

Basic example below, it also support nested sub-commands (like git), etc.

```c
static cmdp_command_st cmdp = {
    .options = {
        {'i', "Int", "Input Int Option", CMDP_TYPE_INT4, &arg.i},
        {0},
    },
    .fn_process = callback,
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return cmdp_run(argc - 1, argv + 1, &cmdp);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).